# $k$-algebra morphisms from formal power series ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, formal-power-series

**Background/Motivation:**

I was playing around with a certain construction that I am trying to generalize and therefore needed to compute some examples to get a feel for the situation. I realized that I don't really feel comfortable with $\text{Hom}_k(k[[t]],-)$ for some field $k$, i.e. with $k$-algebra morphisms from a formal power series ring. One of the first examples I considered led to the following question:

**The question:**

Let $k$ be an arbitrary field and consider the set of $k$-algebra homomorphisms $\text{Hom}_k(k[[t]],k)$. How do the elements look like?

**My thoughts:**

At first it feels like such a morphism is determined by the value of $t$ which cannot be since

1) The $k$-algebra morphism doesnt allow us to commute with our infinite (formal) sums.

2) Then we would have $k[[t]] \cong k[t]$ as this is the universal property of the polynomial ring as free $k$-algebra.

So that is not what we are looking for.
We certainly have the $t \mapsto 0$ morphism, but if $t$ is not sent to $0$, I am confused. Somehow it feels like the set of these morphisms is given (rather: can be identified) by all elements $a \in k$, such that all these formals sums "converge" if I plug in $a$. But now $k$ is not necessarily a topological field and hence talking about convergence does not seem to be the correct way of thinking. Thus "converge" should mean define an element in $k$ here, but I don't really know.

Comment: As a general comment: $k[[t]]$ is by definition a (projective) limit, which means that it is easy to define morphisms *to* $k[[t]]$, but it is hard to define morphisms *from* $k[[t]]$.

Comment: @CaptainLama Exactly! It is the limit of $k[t]/(t^m)$. I am still hoping that (maybe under some assumptions on the target) one can understand these Hom-sets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$k[[t]]$ is actually local, its only maximal ideal is $\mathfrak{m}=(t)$. To see that, you take a power series $f=\sum_{i}a_it^i$ with $a_0 \neq 0$ (so that $f \notin \mathfrak{m}$) and recursively find its formal inverse (So every element outside of $\mathfrak{m}$ is invertible, hence $\mathfrak{m}$ is the unique maximal ideal).

Since you are surjecting onto a field (this is forced by the assumption that we have a $k$-algebra homomorphism), kernel of any such homomorphism is maximal, i.e. $\mathfrak{m}$.

So there is only one such homomorphism: the one sending $t$ to $0$ and constants to constants.

---

Regarding the general situation, i.e. $k$-algebra maps from $k[[t]]$ to a $k$-algebra $A$: For complete topological $k$-algebras $A$ and continuous maps, the answer should be "topologically nilpotent elements". Unfortunately, we do not assume topology on $A$, and I have trouble pinpointing what this should mean in an abstract $k$-algebra (so that the description would not be more or less tautological).

Let me start by describing the easy cases, which are maps $\varphi: k[[t]] \rightarrow A$ that are not injective. Since $k[[t]]$ is a DVR with a uniformizer $t$, the kernel has to be of the form $(t^n)$ for some $n$, and so $\varphi$ factors through $k[[t]]/(t^n)=k[t]/(t^n)$. From the standard description of the maps $k[t]\rightarrow A,$ one sees that these correspond to (*actually*) nilpotent elements of $A$.

Now we have to consider "only" the case of injections $\varphi: k[[t]] \hookrightarrow A$. Here I have trouble in describing these in terms of elements or anything else sensible  - I guess the best is "complete DVR subrings of $A$ with residue field $k$ together with a choice of uniformizer" (here the uniformizer should be the topologically nilpotent element in question).

It also does not relate particularly well to the maps $k[t] \rightarrow A$:

For example, obviously not every map $k[t] \rightarrow A$ extends to $k[[t]]\rightarrow A$ (just consider the situation when $k[t]\rightarrow A$ maps $t$ to some $a \in A$, alebraic over $k$ and not nilpotent).

However, also some maps $k[t] \rightarrow A$ may allow for multiple extensions: just consider the structure map of $k[t] \rightarrow k[[t]]\otimes_{k[t]}k[[t]]=:A$. There are two obvious extensions, namely sending $k[[t]]$ to the copy of itself on the left and on the right, resp. (note that in this example, just choosing the uniformizer - $t$ in both cases, is not enough, one actually needs to choose the copy of $k[[t]]$ inside $A$. In topological setting, this would be already determined by the topology (at least when $A$ is "complete and separated")).

Some good news at the end: Let me also point out that a necessary condition for an injection $k[[t]] \rightarrow A$ to exist is that $A$ has uncountable transcendence degree over $k$. So this means e.g. that for all $k$-algebras of finite type, maps $k[[t]] \rightarrow A$ will neatly correspond precisely to nilpotent elements of $A$.

Comment: You are totally right, thanks. I overlooked that all these morphisms are surjective. Do you know whether there is a description for the set $\text{Hom}_k(k[[t]],A)$ for some arbitrary $k$-algebra $A$? (as in the case of the polynomials ring which leads to the identification with $A$)

Comment: @RobertMuller I realized that and subsequently started writing just that. I will edit in a few minutes.

Comment: @RobertMuller Actually there is some subtlety in what I wanted to write. I will try to write it up properly later. In the meantime, let me just point to [universal property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Universal_property) of power series rings, which gives you an idea along which lines the answer lies. In general, the answer will be connected to some topology as you pointed out as well, the trick is that the map itself will define the relevant topology.

Comment: @RobertMuller I finally added what I know - unfortunately, it is not much, just a few observations. The problem is that $k[[t]]$ works, unsurprisingly. well with topological rings, but not so well with general rings.

Comment: I was not able to login anymore so I could not accept the answer until now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If $A$ is a $k$-algebra with the $I$-adic topology (with $I\subset A$ an ideal), I understand why continuous $k$-algebra homomorphisms $k[t]\to A$ correspond to topologically nilpotent elements in $A$. But what's the situation with a general topological $k$-algebra $A$? If $\varphi:k[t]\to A$ sends $t$ to a topologically nilpotent $x\in A$, I don't see why $f_n(t)\in k[t]$ convergent to zero should imply $\varphi(f_n)=f_n(x)$ convergent to zero. I can prove it if $f_n$ had at most $N<+\infty$ non-zero monomials for all $n\gg 0$. But what happens in a case like $f_n=\sum_{i=n}^{2n}t^i$?

Comment: I just found the statement of the universal property in finitely-many variables for linear topologies. The following is Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra with a View Towards Algebraic Geometry*, theorem 7.16: Let $R$ be any ring and let $S$ be an $R$-algebra that is complete with respect to some ideal $\mathfrak{n}$. Given $f_1,\dots, f_n\in\mathfrak{n}$, there is a unique $R$-algebra homomorphism $\varphi:R[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]\to S$ sending $x_i$ to $f_i$ for each $i$. The map $\varphi$ takes a power series $g(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ to $g(f_1,\dots,f_n)\in S$.