# Algebra morphisms $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n],\mathbb C[t,x_1,\dots,x_n])$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra

Consider the polynomial algebras $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ and $\mathbb C[t,x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

Clearly $\phi_t: x_i \to t x_i$ extended to an algebra homomorphism from $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ to $\mathbb C[t,x_1,\dots,x_n]$.

My question is how to find all the **algebra** morphisms: $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n],\mathbb C[t,x_1,\dots,x_n])$? Also, any such map lifts to a map between $\mathbb C[[x_1,\dots,x_n]]$ to $\mathbb C[[t,x_1,\dots,x_n]]$?

I am not familiar with commutative algebra much. So the following question may be broad. Sorry for this. I am just wondering among all the maps in $\text{Hom}_{\mathbb C}(\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n],\mathbb C[t,x_1,\dots,x_n])$ the map $\phi_t$ satisfies any special properties or of any particular importance?

Thanks for your valuable time.

Comment: For any $\Bbb C$-algebra $A$, the algebra morphisms $\Bbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]\to A$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the functions $\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\to A$, given by restriction and substitution.

Comment: @Berci Thank you. What are restriction and substitution?

Comment: If a homomorphism from the polynomial algebra is given, restrict it to the set of indeterminates. If an arbitrary function on the indeterminates is given, extend it to the polynomial algebra by substituting the indeterminates along the given function, that will define an algebra morphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To elaborate on Berci's comment: $\Bbb{C}[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ satisfies the following universal property:

> For any $\Bbb{C}$-algebra $A,$ the map \begin{align*}\operatorname{Hom}_\Bbb{C}(\Bbb{C}[x_1,\dots, x_n],A)&\to\operatorname{Mor}_{\mathsf{Set}}(\{x_1,\dots, x_n\},A)\\ f&\mapsto \left.f\right|_{\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}}\end{align*} is a bijection.

Here, the map $\left. f\right|_{\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}}$ is the restriction of the algebra morphism to the subset $\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}\subseteq\Bbb{C}[x_1,\dots, x_n].$ That is, if $i : \{x_1,\dots, x_n\}\to\Bbb{C}[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ is the inclusion, then the $\Bbb{C}$-algebra morphism $f : \Bbb{C}[x_1,\dots, x_n]\to A$ induces the map of sets $\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}\xrightarrow{i} \Bbb{C}[x_1,\dots, x_n]\xrightarrow{f}A.$

The question is then, how does one take a map of sets $g : \{x_1,\dots, x_n\}\to A$ and extend it to a $\Bbb{C}$-algebra map $\tilde{g} : \Bbb{C}[x_1,\dots, x_n]\to A$? The idea is that any $\Bbb{C}$-algebra map is completely determined by the images of the $x_i$ by virtue of being a $\Bbb{C}$-algebra map. For example, suppose that $g(x_i) = a_i\in A,$ and suppose that $g$ extends to an algebra map $\tilde{g}.$ Then for an arbitrary polynomial $\sum_{I\subseteq\Bbb{N}^n} b_I \underline{x}^I$ (we define $\underline{x}^{(e_1,\dots, e_n)} := x_1^{e_1} x_2^{e_2}\cdots x_n^{e_n}$), we must have
\begin{align*}
\tilde{g}\left(\sum_{I\subseteq\Bbb{N}^n} b_I \underline{x}^I\right) &= \sum_{I\subseteq\Bbb{N}^n} \tilde{g}(b_I \underline{x}^I)\\
&= \sum_{I\subseteq\Bbb{N}^n} b_I \tilde{g}(\underline{x}^I)\\
&= \sum_{I\subseteq\Bbb{N}^n} b_I \underline{a}^I.
\end{align*}
The point is now that taking the above to be the definition of $\tilde{g},$ $\tilde{g}$ is a morphism of $\Bbb{C}$-algebras which sends each $x_i$ to $a_i,$ as desired. You should check for yourself any unverified details, including that this assignment $g\mapsto\tilde{g}$ and the previous assignment $f\mapsto\left. f\right|_{\{x_1,\dots, x_n\}}$ are mutually inverse.

To answer your question about power series, the answer is no, not all $\Bbb{C}$-algebra maps $f : \Bbb{C}[x_1,\dots, x_n]\to\Bbb{C}[t,x_1,\dots, x_n]$ lift to maps $\tilde{f} : \Bbb{C}[\![x_1,\dots, x_n]\!]\to\Bbb{C}[\![t,x_1,\dots, x_n]\!].$ The point now is that elements of the left hand side are infinite power series in the $x_i$ with coefficients in $\Bbb{C},$ and the elements of the right hand side are power series in $t$ and the $x_i$ with coefficients in $\Bbb{C}.$ In particular, there are now convergence issues to deal with.

For example, consider the map
\begin{align*}
f : \Bbb{C}[x]&\to\Bbb{C}[t,x]\\
x&\mapsto 1
\end{align*}
(that is, $f$ is the algebra map associated to the map of sets which sends $x$ to $1$). This does not lift to a map of power series rings: the power series $x + x^2 + x^3 + \dots + x^n + \cdots$ should be sent to the infinite sum $1 + 1^2 + \dots + 1^n + \cdots,$ but this sum does not converge!

One universal property of $\Bbb{C}[\![x_1,\dots, x_n]\!]$ is the following:

> Let $(A,\mathfrak{m})$ be a complete local $\Bbb{C}$-algebra. Then the map
> \begin{align*}
> \operatorname{Hom}_{\Bbb{C},\textrm{cont}}(\Bbb{C}[\![x_1,\dots, x_n]\!],A)&\to\{f\in\operatorname{Mor}_{\mathsf{Set}}(\{x_1,\dots,x_n\},A)\mid f(x_i)\in\mathfrak{m}\textrm{ for all }i\}\\
> \phi&\mapsto\left.\phi\right|_{\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}}
> \end{align*}
> is a bijection, where the left hand side is the set of continuous $\Bbb{C}$-homomorphisms, considering $\Bbb{C}[\![x_1,\dots, x_n]\!]$ with its $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$-adic topology and $A$ with its $\mathfrak{m}$-adic topology.

More generally, in order to define a [continuous] $\Bbb{C}$-algebra homomorphism $\phi : \Bbb{C}[\![x_1,\dots, x_n]\!]\to A$ for any [topological] $\Bbb{C}$-algebra $A,$ you need $\phi(x_i)$ to be [topologically] nilpotent in $A,$ so that the image of any power series will actually converge in $A.$ In general, it's hard to define maps out of $\Bbb{C}[\![x_1,\dots, x_n]\!],$ because it is defined as a limit rather than a colimit. When we restrict our attention to continuous maps (with respect to the $(x_1,\dots, x_n)$-adic topology), it becomes easier. For more discussion, you might check out the answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3579795/k-algebra-morphisms-from-formal-power-series-ring).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In your example, you have mapped $x \to 1$. Suppose none of the $x_1,\dots,x_n$ is mapped to a scalar, then the map can be lifted to the power series ring? For example, consider the map $\phi_t$ in the question. I want only such maps to lifts to the power series ring. Thank you.

Comment: @GA316 Like I said, you need each $x_i$ to be mapped to a topologically nilpotent element. For example, it suffices for each $\phi(x_i)$ to be a power series with constant term zero (this would be a special case of the universal property I mentioned for power series rings -- power series with no constant term are precisely elements of the maximal ideal of $\Bbb{C}[\![t,x_1,\dots, x_n]\!]$). However, a map like $\phi(x_i) = 2 + x_i t$ will also not lift, although no $\phi(x_i)$ is a scalar.

Comment: Thank you. Now I understand the importance of nilpotency. If we don't worry about the convergence and want to work in the level of combinatorial formal power series such a lift is possible? For example, the map $\phi_t$ in the question can be lifted to the ring of power series?

Comment: @GA316 Your map $\phi_t$ can be lifted using the universal property I gave in the answer, because $tx_i\in (t,x_1,\dots, x_n)$ for all $i.$ It lifts to a continuous map $\Bbb{C}[\![x_1,\dots, x_n]\!]\to\Bbb{C}[\![t,x_1,\dots, x_n]\!]$ (giving both rings their adic topologies) which is defined by the "obvious" formula. If you don't care about continuity, I suspect that more maps will be liftable using some sort of choice to compatibly choose images of all possible power series, but I've never considered such things -- generally, maps from and to complete local rings should be continuous.

Comment: Thank you. I would like to add your universal property in my paper. Can you suggest some reference to cite in my paper? Thanks a lot for the nice conversation.

Comment: @GA316 a more general statement is theorem 7.16 in Eisenbud's "Commutative Algebra with a View Towards Algebraic Geometry." In fact, chapter 7 there is on "Completions and Hensel's Lemma," and section 7.6 deals in particular with "Maps from Power Series Rings."

Comment: Thank you very much :)